# Python download attachments from outlook, not looping thru each attachment per email

Tags: python, email, outlook, automation, win32com

This code goes into Outlook and downloads each email's attachments. The problem is that it only downloads (1) per email. I need it to download all per email.
This is my first program, any tips, advice appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
import win32com.client


outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI") #Opens Microsoft Outlook
folder = outlook.Folders[3]            #N4 Invocie folder
subFolder = folder.Folders[5]          #N4 Invoice subfolder
subFolderMessages = subFolder.Items    #Invoice items object
message = subFolderMessages.GetFirst()

while True:
    subFolderItemAttachments = message.Attachments
    nbrOfAttachmentInMessage = subFolderItemAttachments.Count
    x = 1
    while x <= nbrOfAttachmentInMessage:
        attachment = subFolderItemAttachments.item(x)
        #Saves attachment to location
        attachment.SaveAsFile('C:\\Users\\kkim\\Desktop\\InvoiceOutlook' + '\\'+ str(attachment)) 
        break    
    message = subFolderMessages.GetNext()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `break` from the attachment while loop.

You first while loop must check for the `message` variable != null.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
import win32com.client


outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI") #Opens Microsoft Outlook
folder = outlook.Folders[3]            #N4 Invocie folder
subFolder = folder.Folders[5]          #N4 Invoice subfolder
subFolderMessages = subFolder.Items    #Invoice items object
message = subFolderMessages.GetFirst()

for attachment in message.attachments:
    attachment.SaveAsFile('C:\\Users\\kkim\\Desktop\\InvoiceOutlook' + '\\'+ str(attachment))
```